# What is the maximum file upload size with xmlhttprequest level 2?

Tags: html, file-upload, xmlhttprequest, xmlhttprequest-level2

What is the maximum file upload size with xmlhttprequest level 2 with HTML5?

Comment: That's going to depend on your server configuration.

Answer (score 8):

The [XMLHttpRequest specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-send-method]) does not mention any limits on the upload size.

In practise, upload requests are limited by:

1. The number of simultaneous uploads: [How many concurrent AJAX (XmlHttpRequest) requests are allowed in popular browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561046/how-many-concurrent-ajax-xmlhttprequest-requests-are-allowed-in-popular-browse)
2. The configured limit on the web server, eg. [`LimitRequestBody`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody) on Apache, [`client_max_body_size`](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size) on Nginx.
3. The limits in the server-side scripting environment, e.g. [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) in PHP.
4. Memory limits ([bugs](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=678648), client-side or server-side).

See also:

- [Send a file with XmlHttpRequest: Streaming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6454365/send-a-file-with-xmlhttprequest-streaming)