# PHP - Upload file reset

Tags: php, apache, file-upload

I'm facing an upload issue using **PHP**.

I upload the file using a form and the input type file provided from HTML, and I have to upload large files (`max size 500MB`).

I have edited my php.ini file in this way:

```
max_execution_time = 7200;
max_input_time = 7200;
memory_limit = 500M;
post_max_size = 500M;
upload_max_filesize = 500M.
```

I made many tests during the last weeks using small files (`20 MB`) and the upload was working fine.
Now I want to simulate the worst situation, when the user have to upload large files. I noticed that when the user tries to upload files larger than 100MB the upload "resets".
The page receives `2048000 bytes`, then it restart from 0 and again, it resets when it reach `2048000 bytes`. This happens for a couple of times then the upload stops.

I tried also to edit my httpd.conf adding the line:

```
LimitRequestBody 524288000
```

The problem is still present. How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you using a shared hosting? Can you check the configuration using <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: Here the details of my php.ini.
[Part one](http://s17.postimg.org/7fb31mcjz/details1.png)
[Part two](http://s17.postimg.org/wzhylsnbj/details2.png)

Comment: Ok, that looks fine. Did you check the error logs?

Comment: No I didn't. Do I have to check the httpd error log?

Comment: Yes `/usr/local/apache/logs/error_log` Here

Comment: Are you using some framework for upload? I think there something makes redirects...

Comment: There are many notice messages about SIGTERM, I think because of the restarts I made when I edited the file php.ini.
There are no other messages.

Comment: @Phoebus No, I'm not using frameworks. I work with the input type file and a code written in JavaScript (it uses an XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: Did you checked out what is written at file upload on server side (PHP)? maybe there is some conditions on file size. Also check out in Chrome developer tools -> Network, what status and response returns that page while trying to upload.

Comment: In the PHP upload file I set a file size check, I will remove it and then I will try again. I will check also the status of the page and then I will let you know. Thank you for the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found what the problem was.**

I never checked the `nginx.conf file`.

There is the an option called `client_max_body_size` that has to be edited.

In my case it was set to `100m (100MB)`, I changed it to `500m` and I solved the problem.

Comment: See the link here for a detailed explanation of what limit an upload:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004544/what-is-the-maximum-file-upload-size-with-xmlhttprequest-level-2